# Unity: How to build a Grid on which GameObjects would snap, both in Editor mode and while playing the game

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-engine, game-development, grid-layout

**I did look at the suggested posts while typing this one and already searched on stackoverflow and youtube. Found a lot of interesting stuff but none really helped me achieve what I need.**

A bit of context: I am a software developer but has zero experience with video games, which is a totally different field of what I have been working all those years.

I decided to create a remake of [PushOver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push-Over_(video_game)). It is purely for myself, the game will not be distributed or anything.

Right now, I am trying to build a mechanism that I will be able to use for two purposes:

1. Building the levels: placing the dominos in the level. They must be evenly spaced (a multiple of a constant as we can have some unoccupied spots) and cannot be placed anywhere I want on the screen. This will be done in editor mode and I will have 100 different scenes, one per level. I am not planing to do a level editor but if it's what I should do please advise me on it
2. In game: moving the dominos around: the ant can take and move a domino, they can be released only at specific locations following the same logic as for the initial placement. The space between the dominos is a multiple of a constant.
3. In game: moving the ant. The ant will basically be able to move only in between the dominos, and the direction it is facing will decide which domino it takes for moving

From what I learnt from the game, you can have at most 20 domino horizontally, and 7 dominos vertically, so it's basically a 7 x 20 grid on which dominos should snap, and the ant should also snap on this grid, except not on the vertices but between them (horizontally)

I have been trying to build a grid that take screen size into consideration. I have a lot of trouble to find the (0, 0) coordinates. It seems to be the camera. Ultimately we went for an hardcoded cellsize. However when I change the size of the screen game in the editor it also change the size of the actual screen size and it scraps the grid.

I don't really know how to tackle this problem and I would need advice on this because I clearly lacks knowledge about Unity and am probably missing functionalities that would help, or simply I am not looking at the problem the correct way.

**Summary:** *How to create a 7x20 grid that will scale with the game screen size so it always fill the whole screen, which (0, 0) origin coordinates will be the bottom left corner of the screen (or any other corner, I don't care, I just don't like it when it's the center), and on which objects can snap, both in editor and play mode.*

Comment: Is this a 2D project or a 3D project? Going off the fact you're wanting it to be like Push-Over, I'm guessing 2D?

Comment: This might be helpful/what you're after?
- https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-Grid.html

Comment: Could be lol ! Can I make it stick to the whole screen and dynamically compute the cell size according to the screensize ?

It is a 2D project

Comment: Yes, but I don't think there is anything that you can use "out of the box", you'll most likely have to code that part yourself It should be relatively straight forward; you can get a reference to the grid component by doing something like `[SerializeField] private Grid grid`. That'll let you alter the grid properties from code. Then you use `Screen.width` and height to get the screen size. After that, it's down to you to work out how you want the grid to look, and how it changes with the screen size